# select angularjs not updating titles after http petition

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http

I've searched a lot before to ask this question but I don't find anything. The problem is that I receive a JSON after a GET petition of server, and receive it correctly (I'm check this) but the select options not reload the info.

This is my code:

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('SelectController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
  
  $scope.data_info = [
    {id:1, name:'Option A'},
    {id:2, name:'Option B'},
    {id:3, name:'Option C'}
    ];
  $scope.data_model = null;

  $http.get('http://localhost:7800/data_info'{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
   .success(function(data) {
    $scope.data_info = data; 
   })
   .error(function(data){
   });
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="SelectController">
  
<select  
        ng-options="d as d.name for d in data_info track by d.id"
        ng-model="data_model">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose an option</option>
        </select>
  
  model: {{data_model}}
  
  </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Change the `track by d.id` to `track by $index`

Comment: This not working, the problem is that not refreshing the data with **ng-options**. If initialize _data.info_ before the http petition, the response of these don't update the _data.info_ values, but if I print the response with **console.log(response)** the data is recevied correctly. @georgeawg

Answer (score 0):

You need a few changes. The code below will work:

Replace in your controller:

```
 $scope.data.model = {};
```

for:

```
 $scope.selectedInfo = null;
 $scope.data.info = {};
```

And on .success:

```
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.data.info = data;
    })
```

On your HTML:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedInfo" 
            ng-options="item as item.name for item in info">
         <option value="" disabled selected>Choose an option</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: The problem persist, if initialize the data with random values before http petition the data is not updated, I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.data` will be undefined. Initialize it like `$scope.data ={info:{}, model:{}};`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the **select** tag is overwrited for materialize.css.

Add `class="browser-default"`  to **select** tag.